# how to resolve NoMethodError in ContactsController#index in ROR-4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help me to resolve this error and reedit my all pages. Actually i am new to Ruby on Rails and i am using rails version-4 and ruby version-1.9.3.I want to show one form including select options and selected value saved in DB. My errors and code snippets explained below.

Error:

```
undefined method `email_providers=' for #<Class:0x4e68df0>

Extracted source (around line #2):
1 class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
2 self.email_providers = %w[Gmail Yahoo MSN]
3 validates :email_provider, :inclusion => email_providers
4 end
```

views/contacts/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @contact,:url => {:action => "create"} do |f|%>
<%= f.text_field:gmail %>
<%= f.select :email_provider, options_for_select(Contact.email_providers, @contact.email_provider) %>
<%= f.submit "Submit"%>
<% end %>
```

controller/contacts_controller.rb

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
def index
@contact=Contact.new
end
def create
end
end
```

models/contact.rb

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
self.email_providers = %w[Gmail Yahoo MSN]
validates :email_provider, :inclusion => email_providers
end
```

migrate/20141222061313_create_contacts.rb

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :gmail
      t.string :yahoo
      t.string :msn

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I want to show the 3 content(gmail,yahoo,msn) in option drop down list and while it will be selected and clicked on submit button it will be saved in DB.Please help me to edit the code.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
self.email_providers = %w[Gmail Yahoo MSN]
validates :email_provider, :inclusion => email_providers
```

in your Contact model class to:

```
EMAIL_PROVIDERS = %w{Gmail Yahoo MSN}
validates :email_provider, inclusion: {in: EMAIL_PROVIDERS}
```

and the error should be fixed.

As you can guess, your Contact class doesn't have a `self.email_providers=` method. So trying to assign a value to it through this method will crash. What I've done is created a constant that can be easily accessed within the class through `EMAIL_PROVIDERS` and outside the class through `Contact::EMAIL_PROVIDERS`

Comment: It should be fixed. Did you restart your server? If yes, then perhaps it's some other error that you're getting now. Check what the exact error is and see if it's the same.